# Update textfield after input

Tags: user-interface, events, text, field

I'm trying to write a GUI with several JTextFields. Two of the fields are for float values. I already have the fields ignoring any non-numerical inputs via a formatter, but I also want the text in the text field to update to a float value if an integer is inputted (i.e. "5" changes to "5.00"). I tried to update the text field using a setText() command from within an event, but the displayed value is not changing. I want the text to change once focus is lost on the text field.

The code is very long, so I will include the relevant snippet.

```
        heightField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            heightDone = !heightField.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("");

            //This is the problem code//
            if(UF.isInt(heightField.getText().trim()))
                heightField.setText(heightField.getText().trim().concat(".00"));

            System.out.println(heightField.getText());
            heightFormat = UF.isFloat(heightField.getText().trim());
            isDone();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to refresh the frame after the change on the textField :

```
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: I have tried that in the code for the event. It didn't work.